# How to create 3 links to define and one to erase

Tags: javascript, html

The document added another 3 link given in such a way that three links define three fruit and the fourth to erase selections

How do I do that?

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script language="javascript">
    <!--
    function FruitBox() {
      window.document.myform.fruit[].checked = true;
    }

    function clearall() {
      for (var p = 1; p < 3; p++) {
        var x = window.document.myform.fruit("value");
        for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
          x[i].checked = false;
      }
    }

    //-->
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <from name="myform">
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" onclick="window.document.myform.fruit.value='oranges'">oranges & Tangerines <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" onclick="window.document.myform.fruit.value='bananas'">bananas <br>
    <input type="radio" name="fruit" onclick="window.document.myform.fruit.value='peaches'">peaches,Nectarines & Palmus <br> To select Oranges <a href="javascript:FruitBox()">click here</a>


    <input type="reset" Value="Sterge" onClick=" clearall()" />
  </from>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: the `for (p` loop looks redundant, why!? and what do you think `window.document.myform.fruit("value");` is? an array? (no)

Answer (score 1):

1. You misspelled tag `form`
2. you need to pass something to the function
3. you need to access that something
4. the reset will reset the form. No need to call a function
5. since you use form access there is no need to address the form from the top of the document but there is ALSO no need to set the value of the fruit on click
6. if you give each radio an ID, you can have a `<label for="oranges">Click here to select oranges</label>` instead of a link

   ```html
   <html>

   <head>
     <script language="javascript">
       function FruitBox(idx) {
         window.document.myform.fruit[idx].checked = true;
         return false; // cancel the link - preventDefault can be used too
       }
   /* NOT needed
       function clearall() {
         for (var p = 1; p < 3; p++) {
           var x = window.document.myform.fruit("value");
           for (var i = 0; i < 4; i++)
             x[i].checked = false;
         }
       }
   */
     </script>
   </head>

   <body>
     <form name="myform">
       <input type="radio" name="fruit">oranges & Tangerines <br>
       <input type="radio" name="fruit">bananas <br>
       <input type="radio" name="fruit">peaches,Nectarines & Palmus <br>
       To select Oranges <a href="#" onclick="return FruitBox(0)">click here</a>


       <input type="reset" Value="Sterge"  />
     </from>
   </body>

   </html>
   ```